# Getting The Url From C# to HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Im trying to do popup video player for my website

My CS Code

```
 public class Products
 {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

 }
```

Page_Load Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var products = new List<Products>();

        products.Add(new Products() { ProductID = 1 , ProductName = "Name1" , Url = "https://google.com"});

        products.Add(new Products() { ProductID = 2, ProductName = "Name2", Url = "https://google.com"});

        products.Add(new Products() { ProductID = 3, ProductName = "Name3", Url = "https://google.com"});

        products.Add(new Products() { ProductID = 4, ProductName = "Name4", Url = "https://google.com"});

    }
```

And finally my html code

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <iframe width="100%" height="500" src="<%# "Url" %>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

</div>
```

What am i trying to do is, getting the URL from the page_load in to the html `<%# "Url" %>` part,

1 - ) How can i achieve this?

2 - ) Whats the efficieny method for something like this?

Comment: How you iterate products list object on html? using repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be simple aspx page, if it's possible it's better to use asp.net MVC.

however it's of course possible to do what you want.
Bellow a quick a dirty exemple.

```
//put products as class variable
protected List<Products> products = new List<Products>();
```

```
<% foreach(var product in products ){ %>
<div id="myModal-<%=product.ProductID %>" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <iframe width="100%" height="500" src="<%=product.Url %>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

</div>
<% }%>
```

Comment: well, tbh i have alreadt tried to <%=product.Url %> but the url didnt even change, but in the end the problem was the my writing style, i have already completed the task, all i have to do was "Project_Name.Product.Url"

Comment: In the code source of rendering page "src", attribute of iframe does change? If it change the problem can come from javascript. In my exemple I have fix a issue of duplicate id (first div).

Comment: yes, it was not changing at the start then i used javascript to change it, now it works properly like i wanted to, thanks